# Setting Cache adding Tildes to Resource Path

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I'm utilizing AWS's CDK to develop our API layer.  Everything has worked so far, and now I am adding in caching.  I enabled `CacheCluster` in the stage and I am trying to enable it for a handful of my endpoints.  The problem I am facing is the CDK is changing the resource path from something like `/v1/configuration` to `/~1v1~1configuration`.  I've tried escaping my `/`s, but that didn't fix my issue.

CDK C# Code

```
new Amazon.CDK.AWS.APIGateway.Stage(this, "prod", new Amazon.CDK.AWS.APIGateway.StageProps
{
    Deployment = deployment,
    StageName = "prod",
    Variables = stageVariables,
    CacheClusterEnabled = true,
    CacheClusterSize = "1.6",
    DataTraceEnabled = true,
    LoggingLevel = MethodLoggingLevel.INFO,
    MetricsEnabled = true,
    TracingEnabled = true,
    MethodOptions = new Dictionary<string, IMethodDeploymentOptions>
    {
        { "/v1/configuration/GET", new MethodDeploymentOptions { CachingEnabled = true }}
    }
});
```

Resulting Method Settings in the stage:

```
MethodSettings:
  - DataTraceEnabled: true
    HttpMethod: "*"
    LoggingLevel: INFO
    MetricsEnabled: true
    ResourcePath: /*
  - CachingEnabled: true
    HttpMethod: GET
    ResourcePath: /~1v1~1configuration
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The forward slashes being encoded to ~1 is expected behavior. Please see:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-apitgateway-stage-methodsetting.html#cfn-apigateway-stage-methodsetting-resourcepath